# Alternate 2 images in Java Game with timer

Tags: java, image, swing, timer, alternate

I'm doing a simple game in Java.
I have one Class named "Drawer" to repaint every 50 miliseconds the images that I save in BufferedImages' s array.

I have a method to convert the player in a huge player in the Player Class and the code is:

```
    public void playerEvolution() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.setImageIndex(15);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            this.setImageIndex(17);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.isHuge();
}
```

I want alternate 2 images every 0.5 seconds but in the GamePanel doesn't alternated any images and only appear the final image when spend 2.5 seconds (0.5 * 5 loops).

Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a Swing application (you don't say), use a javax.swing.Timer or Swing Timer. Never call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the main Swing event thread, known as the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT.  Have an int count variable in your Timer's ActionListener which is incremented each time `actionPerformed(...)` is called, and stop the Timer if the count > to a max count (here 5 * 2 since you're swapping back and forth).

e.g.,

```
public void playerEvolution() {
  int delay = 500; // ms
  javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(delay , new ActionListener() {
     private int count = 0;
     private int maxCount = 5;

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (count < maxCount * 2) {
           count++;
           // check if count is even to decide 
           // which image to use, and then
           // do your image swapping here
        } else {
           ((javax.swing.Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for an animation. See [`https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/graphics/Animation.java`](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/graphics/Animation.java)